# The type initializer for 'NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration' threw an exception

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I am using FluentNHibernate and during the configuration phase I am getting the following error:

Here is the configuration:

public static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
        {
            return
                Fluently.Configure().Database(
                    MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2000.ConnectionString(
                        c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("HighOnCodingConnectionString")))
                        .Mappings(m =>
      m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf())
      .BuildSessionFactory();
        }

And here is the error:

[failure] when_instantiating_a_session_factory.should_be_able_to_create_a_session_factory
TestCase 'when_instantiating_a_session_factory.should_be_able_to_create_a_session_factory'
failed: The type initializer for 'NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration' threw an exception.
    System.TypeInitializationException
    Message: The type initializer for 'NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration' threw an exception.
    Source: NHibernate
    StackTrace:
    at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration..ctor()
    c:\FluentNHibernate\src\FluentNHibernate\Cfg\FluentConfiguration.cs(25,0): at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration..ctor()
    c:\FluentNHibernate\src\FluentNHibernate\Cfg\Fluently.cs(16,0): at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Fluently.Configure()
    C:\Projects\highoncodingmvc\src\highoncoding\src\HighOnCoding.BusinessObjects\Factories\SessionFactory.cs(17,0): at HighOnCoding.BusinessObjects.Factories.SessionFactory.CreateSessionFactory()
    C:\Projects\highoncodingmvc\src\highoncoding\src\HighOnCoding.TestSuite\Configuration\TestFluentNHiberate.cs(17,0): at HighOnCoding.TestSuite.Configuration.when_instantiating_a_session_factory.should_be_able_to_create_a_session_factory()
    Inner Exception
    System.IO.FileLoadException
    Message: The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
    Source: NHibernate
    StackTrace:
    at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration..cctor()

Here is the log information from FusionLog thing:

*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (6/21/2009 @ 12:49:38 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
Running under executable  C:\Projects\highoncodingmvc\src\highoncoding\src\HighOnCodingConsole\bin\Debug\HighOnCodingConsole.exe
--- A detailed error log follows.

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = D9SKQBG1\AzamSharp
LOG: DisplayName = NHibernate.XmlSerializers, Version=2.0.1.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4, processorArchitecture=MSIL
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Projects/highoncodingmvc/src/highoncoding/src/HighOnCodingConsole/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = NULL

## Calling assembly : System.Xml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.

LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Projects\highoncodingmvc\src\highoncoding\src\HighOnCodingConsole\bin\Debug\HighOnCodingConsole.exe.Config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: NHibernate.XmlSerializers, Version=2.0.1.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4, processorArchitecture=MSIL
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Projects/highoncodingmvc/src/highoncoding/src/HighOnCodingConsole/bin/Debug/NHibernate.XmlSerializers.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Projects/highoncodingmvc/src/highoncoding/src/HighOnCodingConsole/bin/Debug/NHibernate.XmlSerializers/NHibernate.XmlSerializers.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Projects/highoncodingmvc/src/highoncoding/src/HighOnCodingConsole/bin/Debug/NHibernate.XmlSerializers.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Projects/highoncodingmvc/src/highoncoding/src/HighOnCodingConsole/bin/Debug/NHibernate.XmlSerializers/NHibernate.XmlSerializers.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've compiled against one version of an assembly, but at execution time it's finding another and complaining. I suggest you [turn on Fusion logging](http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57120.aspx) to work out what's going on - in particular, the exact assembly which is causing problems!

Comment: But how is that possible! I just got the DLL's from FluentNHibernate website and added reference to all the assemblies manually!

Comment: It may be loading an assembly from the GAC at execution time. The best way to find out is to use fusion logging...

Comment: The strange thing is that I just added a Console Application and use the same code for setting up the session factory and it worked fine with no errors.

Comment: I have edited the original post to include the log information from Fusion. Seems like the culprit is NHibernate.XmlSerializers but this assembly is not included by the FluentNHibernate download!

Comment: I also tried the code to insert into the database and it worked for a Console Application without any trouble!

Comment: Weird thing again!!! I just removed all the assemblies from the test project except the NHibernate and then it worked fine and the test passed! This problem should be documented by the FluentNHibernate team!

Comment: Which would support Jon's answer.  This should be accepted as an answer also.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is long since resolved, but having had this problem myself today, I found this as my personal solution and thought I'd share the knowledge:

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2399679

From the post:

*"My debugger in Visual Studio was set to break on all exceptions, adjusting the exception settings fixed my problem."*

Also led me to:

http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2008/02/13/sgenexe-and-strongly-named-assemblies/

*"After some search I found that the xxxx.XmlSerializers assembly is a pregenerated assembly that the xmlserializers looks for before attempting to generate one at runtime..."*